# Babel evaluate variable into string

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

As the title, babel evaluates variable into string and deletes variable.

```js
const url = config.app.url + "/api/posts/1"
// config values are dynamic. 
this.load(url)
```

When papel parse this code and turned into es5 code it shows

```js
// const url = config.app.url + "/api/posts/1" - deleted

this.load("http://app.test/api/posts/1")
```

So in the production server, it sends request to test address not the real address.

How to avoid from this compilation ?

Comment: Share your babel and webpack configs.

Comment: @sdgluck I'm using default laravel - mix configurations

Comment: How are you setting `config.app.url`?

Comment: I imported it from config.json (local file) @sdgluck

Comment: I believe this is because you are using `const` babel is optimizing the code because, by default, url can never change. Consider using `let`

Comment: @SeanKelly I tried with `let` too, gives same result :/

Comment: @TeomanTıngır ah dang. Wish I could help. I haven't worked with laravel since 5.5

Comment: still thanks your advice :) @SeanKelly